# How to create AWS AppConfig across organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config, aws-app-config

Is possible to create an AWS AppConfig Deployment Strategy through all accounts of an AWS Organization easily with the same Id?

`aws appconfig get-deployment-strategy --deployment-strategy-id 2lzu2vi`

```
{
    "Id": "2lzu2vi",
    "Name": "Test.Canary10Percent60Minutes",
    "DeploymentDurationInMinutes": 60,
    "GrowthType": "EXPONENTIAL",
    "GrowthFactor": 10.0,
    "FinalBakeTimeInMinutes": 10,
    "ReplicateTo": "NONE"
}
```

I'm expectating creating new deployment strategies of AWS Appconfig easily in all accounts automatically.